# Why is valarray so slow on Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, optimization, valarray

To speed up the calculations in my library, I decided to use the `std::valarray` class. The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) says:

> std::valarray and helper classes are defined to be free of certain
>   forms of aliasing, thus allowing operations on these classes to be
>   optimized similar to the effect of the keyword restrict in the C
>   programming language. In addition, functions and operators that take
>   valarray arguments are allowed to return proxy objects to make it
>   possible for the compiler to optimize an expression such as v1 = a * v2
>   + v3; as a single loop that executes v1[i] = a * v2[i] + v3[i]; avoiding any temporaries or multiple passes.

This is exactly what I need. And it works as described in the documentation when I use the g++ compiler. I have developed a simple example to test the `std::valarray` performance:

```
void check(std::valarray<float>& a)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
      if (a[i] != 7)
         std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   const int N = 100000000;
   std::valarray<float> a(1, N);
   std::valarray<float> c(2, N);
   std::valarray<float> b(3, N);
   std::valarray<float> d(N);

   auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
   d = a + b * c;
   auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

   std::cout << "Valarr optimized case: "
      << (end - start).count() << std::endl;

   check(d);

   // Optimal single loop case
   start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      d[i] = a[i] + b[i] * c[i];
   end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
   std::cout << "Optimal case: " << (end - start).count() << std::endl;

   check(d);
   return 0;
}
```

On g++ I got:

```
Valarr optimized case: 1484215
Optimal case: 1472202
```

It seems that all operations `d = a + b * c;` are really placed in one cycle, which simplifies the code while maintaining performance. However, this does not work when I use Visual Studio 2015. For the same code, I get:

```
Valarr optimized case: 6652402
Optimal case: 1766699
```

The difference is almost four times; there is no optimization! Why is `std::valarray` not working as needed on Visual Studio 2015? Am I doing everything right? How can I solve the problem without abandoning `std::valarray`?

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations on VS2015?

Comment: I used Release platform on VS and -O2 optimisation for g++

Comment: Look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6851413/11472661 .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Am I doing everything right?

You're doing everything right. The problem is in the Visual Studio `std::valarray` implementation.

> Why is `std::valarray` not working as needed on Visual Studio 2015?

Just open the implementation of any `valarray` operator, for example `operator+`. You will see something like (after macro expansion):

```
   template<class _Ty> inline
      valarray<_Ty> operator+(const valarray<_Ty>& _Left,
         const valarray<_Ty>& _Right)
   {
      valarray<TYPE> _Ans(_Left.size());
      for (size_t _Idx = 0; _Idx < _Ans.size(); ++_Idx)
         _Ans[_Idx] = _Left[_Idx] + _Right[_Idx];
      return (_Ans)
   }
```

As you can see, a new object is created in which the result of the operation is copied. There really is no optimization. I do not know why, but it is a fact. It looks like in Visual Studio, `std::valarray` was added for compatibility only.

For comparison, consider the [GNU implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/libstdc++/api/a01573_source.html). As you can see, each [operator](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/046ae677a4675ceffb3f028e09ae52a7801a7422/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/valarray#L1151) returns the template class [_Expr](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/valarray_after.h#L163) which contains only the [operation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/valarray_after.h#L204), but does not contain data. The real computation is performed in the [assignment operator](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/046ae677a4675ceffb3f028e09ae52a7801a7422/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/valarray#L834) and more specifically in the [__valarray_copy](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/41d6b10e96a1de98e90a7c0378437c3255814b16/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/valarray_array.tcc#L142) function. Thus, until you perform assignment, all actions are performed on the proxy object `_Expr`. Only once `operator=` is called, is the operation stored in `_Expr` performed in a single loop. This is the reason why you get such good results with g++.

> How can I solve the problem?

You need to find a suitable  `std::valarray` implementation on the internet or you can write your own. You can use the GNU implementation as an example.

Comment: I read an article about how `valarray` never quite had the performance that it was intended to have, in any compiler, so as a result, MSVC never bothered to optimize it, because it was always slow regardless.

Comment: I looked in the GNU `valarray`  implementation. In this implementation, a template proxy object is returned and real calculations only occur when assigning. Performance is only slightly below the explicit use of cycles. Looks like it’s still possible to get effective `valarray`.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/308961/stdvalarray.html for MS reply to a bug report.

Comment: @DmytroDadyka: You misunderstand. Microsoft's claim was that even with the optimizations in GNU, the `valarray` was only very slightly faster than the naive version, and still significantly slower than assembly using the desired commands.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-does-nobody-seem-to-use-std-valarray/answer/Daniel-N%C3%A4slund Reading this, I vaguely remember that the problem was that users would make copies too often by accident, which completely negated the performance gains.  Now that we have move constructors, that may or may not be better.