# Efficient way to XOR two unsigned char arrays?

Tags: c++, performance, encryption, xor

I am implementing an encryption algorithm and was wondering if there was a more efficient way than O(n) for xoring two unsigned char arrays? I essentially want to know if it's possible to avoid doing something like this:

```
   unsigned char a1[64];
   unsigned char a2[64];
   unsigned char result[64];

   for (int i=0;i<64;i++)
   {

       result[i] = a1[i] ^ a2[i];
   
   }
```

Like I said, I know there's nothing inherently *wrong* with doing this but I was wondering if there was possibly a more efficient method. I need to keep my algorithm as streamlined as possible.

Thanks in advance for any information!

Comment: you cannot so something with N array elements in less than `O(N)` (unless there is a way to not touch some of the elements because their value can be inferred from other elements)

Comment: Possibly you could work with elements bigger than `unsigned char` but that would still be O(N), which obviously can't be beaten.

Comment: For AVX512, it is O(1) core-wise using 512-bit operation, for up to 64 char-elements. But with just xor, memory is performance limiter.

Comment: AVX512 is a good idea, details : but it will still be O(n). With 64 bytes n==1

Comment: If offloaded to GPU, it will be O(1) GPU-wise until N=~10k. But data copying is still O(N) (and much slower than CPU accessing RAM).

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik thats cheating. You can always put a limit on `N` and then any algorithm will be `O(1)`. Anyhow, if OP is interested in arrays of size 64 then big-O complexity is rather irrelevant

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number This makes sense, I suppose the overhead really is quite negligible anyway.

Comment: Have you tried loop unrolling?  Performing more data operations inside the loop reduces the number of compares and increments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments note, the only way of doing this faster than O(n) is not doing it for all elements, In fact, don't do it for **any** elements!

The reason is that you're writing a cryptographic algorithm. You'll use `results[i]` a few lines lower. That part will likely be numerically expensive, while this XOR is limited by memory bandwidth. If you replace `results[i]` with `a1[i] ^ a2[i]` in the cryptographic operation, the CPU is likely to overlap the memory access and the computation.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense actually.

Answer (score 1):

With AVX512 it will look like this :

```
//unsigned char a1[64];
//unsigned char a2[64];
//unsigned char result[64];

#include <cstdint>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

union int512
{
    std::uint8_t bytes[64]{};
    __m512 value;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const int512 value)
{
    bool comma = false;
    for (const auto& byte : value.bytes)
    {
        if (comma) std::cout << ", ";
        std::cout << std::hex << "0x" << static_cast<int>(byte);
        comma = true;
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    int512 data1;
    int512 data2;

    std::uint8_t n{ 0u };
    for (auto& byte : data1.bytes) byte = n++;
    for (auto& byte : data2.bytes) byte = 0xff;

    int512 result;
    result.value = _mm512_xor_ps(data1.value, data2.value);

    std::cout << "data1 = " << data1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "data2 = " << data2 << "\n";
    std::cout << "xor   = " << result << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you don't even need to do that. All modern compilers can auto-vectorize those trivial loops https://godbolt.org/z/q3cPo8hrh

Comment: Yes compilers are good at that. And in more complex situations they can also optimize for the pipelining of the CPU (this was just a good excuse for me to try an intrinsic manually for once)

Answer (score 0):

And maybe, with luck, the good old `std::valarray` will be also very fast.

```
#include <valarray>

std::valarray<char> a1(64);
std::valarray<char> a2(64);
std::valarray<char> result(64);

int main() {
    result = a1 ^ a2;
}
```

Please read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates)

But I think that a good optimizing compiler will outperform all our manual and handwriten optimization attempts . . .

Comment: no you should never use `std::valarray` because it's very slow: [Why don't std::valarray get more attention from all C++ compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71951442/995714), [Why is valarray so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6850807/995714), [Why is valarray so slow on Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56050322/995714). Compilers optimize a normal array or vector better and vectorize them but not valarray